# Facebook connect: How the javascript part works?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Actually, I am making a simple page in Symfony2.2. I've got the following codes in a twig template:

```
<!-- facebook link -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=297720976910223";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
<!-- end facebook link-->
```

They successfully do the following:

- display a facebook login button on my page.
- when I click on the button, I can enter my Facebook account.
- I get my Facebook name displayed on my page.

Now what I wish to do is: After having entered a valid Facebook account on the Facebook popup, once I get back on my page, I can alert somthing. For example something like:

```
function after_click() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("Facebook user is connected");
            }
        });
```

..The problem is that I don't exactly how it works. I have tried several options in my codes and searched the net, but in vain.

Any one could explain me the principles for the above and guide me through?
(PS: My final objective is to replace the 'alert' code by a code which redirects the user to another page.)

Thank you alots.

@Thomas, thank you for your answer.. But I really don't understand why the following gives me an alert only when the btnTest is clicked (alert="You clicked on me for a test.."); other alerts are never displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '297720976910223', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here    
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        alert("test connection");
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // connected
          alert("connected");
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // not_authorized
          alert("not authorized");
        } else {
          // not_logged_in
          alert("not logged in");
        }
       }, true);

  };

  function testme()
  {
     alert("You clicked on me for a test..");
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          alert("xxx_");
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // connected
          alert("connected");
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // not_authorized
          alert("not authorized");
        } else {
          // not_logged_in
          alert("not logged in");
        }
       });

  }

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>


<fb:login-button onlogin="testme()" autologoutlink='true' perms='email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream'></fb:login-button>

<!-- Just for testing purposes-->
<button type="button" name="btnTest" onclick="testme()">Test</button>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" onlogin="testme()" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>

</body>    
</html>
```

### PS: On facebook dev website its written:

Prerequisites:

### You'll need somewhere that lets you host HTML files online. If you haven't got one, you can get set up quickly at no cost with Heroku.

I'm testing that file on my PC; does that make a difference..?

Comment: after subscribing to `auth.login` event you call `FB.getLoginStatus`. FB is not yet loaded or for that matter initialized. Here your script encounters an error and the rest is never executed. Therefore the FB SDK is never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The function `FB.getLoginStatus` only tells you, whether the user is authenticated with your application, not if he just logged in.

You can register a listener on login status change to `connected`:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // handle the login
});
```

More info on [FB JavaScript SDK Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).